# Only hidden fields are posted

Tags: php, html, post

This is a first, never saw this in my life, and I do this job for the past 20 years...

I have a customer, with a form issue, when you submit the form only the hidden fields and static values are send.

Simulation...

In the code I have this

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_kocgc&format=raw&task=preview_card&lang=en" method="post" name="ko_cgc" id="ko_cgc">
    <input type="text" name="ko_smail" id="ko_smail" class="koInputBox" value="Bill" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="123"> 
    <div class="btn btn-warning koBtn" id="koBtnSave">Save</div>
    </form>
```

If i enter in the textbox "is sad" next to Bill, now I have "Bill is sad" in the the textbox. If I submit it I only get Bill and the 123 of the hidden field ID, If I empty the field the javascript will tell the field is empty If I enter Ginger in the textbox and submit it I always receive Bill, but if I intercept with javascript the form, everything is perfect, only on the server side (PHP) I got the empty form??????

I use print_r($_POST); to see the result

This code is working fine on another server only on this server I got this weird issue.

I ask this question here just in case someone already experience this and found why, because I pretty sure this will be in my weird book for a long time :O)

If I found It I will post the reason.

A big thanks

EDIT

Here the javascript I use to submit the form

```
jQuery('#koBtnSave').click(function(){      
        var valid = validField(jQuery("#ko_smail"), "text");            
        if(valid == true) {
            jQuery("#ko_cgc").attr("action","index.php?option=com_kocgc&format=raw&task=save_card&lang=en");
            jQuery("#ko_cgc").attr("target","_self");
            jQuery("#ko_cgc").submit();
        }       
    });
```

the validField function only check if(field.attr("value") == "") { and return false if empty. If I do a alert or a concole.log of jQuery("#ko_smail").attr("value") I have the correct value only on the PHP side when I do a print_r($_POST) I got the bad value ????

I put this on hold until tomorrow I will investigate more.

regards

Comment: where is your js code? you have NO SUBMIT button in your form. so you handle submit somewhere in your js code?

Comment: You mentioned a JavaScript validation, can you post the part where you send the data? Is it just letting the form action run? or is it doing some funky serialization of the data?

Comment: edit with more code (js and PHP)

Answer (score 1):

why using `div` instead of `submit` button?

```
<div class="btn btn-warning koBtn" id="koBtnSave">Save</div>
```

change it to something like this:

```
<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-warning koBtn" id="koBtnSave" value="Save" />
```

Comment: And what will happen?

Comment: when the submit button is clicked the form will be submited.

Comment: Well, we are not sure how he is submitting the form. Probably he is using js to serialize to the form. I am lettting him test his code with this one.

Comment: I edit my post to add the missing javascript, I use the Jquery click method on the DIV, I think it's the same as a button or a input:submit I think... maybe I'm wrong :O), but like I said this code is working great on other server, only on this particular server I got the weird issue. It is so weird to me I can believe it.

Comment: Why using js when you can do it using plain html, that is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I found the answer of this weird issue.

The customer have the CloudFlare cache enable for his website, I ask to disable it and the problem was gone, I ask to enable it and restore the original setting and the problem is history.

I think he play in the setting and do something about the form.

Anyway it was a code 12 :O)

Regards to all